# Make a folder inside the drupal installation public

Tags: users

I am trying to make a folder inside my Drupal installation and make it public, which means in my HostGator account I have a folder `public_html`, which has Drupal installed in it; and I have created a folder called `test` and am trying to access it like,

mydomain.com/test

But I am getting mydomain's maintenance message (this is because my primary domain is in maintenance mode, so no issues there)

```
#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

# Override PHP settings that cannot be changed at runtime. See
# sites/default/default.settings.php and drupal_environment_initialize() in
# includes/bootstrap.inc for settings that can be changed at runtime.

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc                 off
  php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off
  php_flag register_globals                 off
  php_flag session.auto_start               off
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
    # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
    # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
    # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
    # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period. This
  # includes directories used by version control systems such as Subversion or
  # Git to store control files. Files whose names begin with a period, as well
  # as the control files used by CVS, are protected by the FilesMatch directive
  # above.
  #
  # NOTE: This only works when mod_rewrite is loaded. Without mod_rewrite, it is
  # not possible to block access to entire directories from .htaccess, because
  # <DirectoryMatch> is not allowed here.
  #
  # If you do not have mod_rewrite installed, you should remove these
  # directories from your webroot or otherwise protect them from being
  # downloaded.
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /

  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  # Various rewrite rules.


  # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
  # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to modify `.htaccess` to ignore specific files/folders.

Set your `.htaccess` in your drupal directory to the following

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/techiequickie/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
```

And put this code right below

```
# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
```

In your Drupal .htaccess

Make sure your htaccess looks like the f0llowing,

```
    #
    # Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
    #

    # Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
    <FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$">
      Order allow,deny
    </FilesMatch>

    # Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
    Options -Indexes

    # Follow symbolic links in this directory.
    Options +FollowSymLinks

    # Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

    # Set the default handler.
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

    # Override PHP settings that cannot be changed at runtime. See
    # sites/default/default.settings.php and drupal_environment_initialize() in
    # includes/bootstrap.inc for settings that can be changed at runtime.

    # PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
      php_flag magic_quotes_gpc                 off
      php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off
      php_flag register_globals                 off
      php_flag session.auto_start               off
      php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
      php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
      php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
    </IfModule>

    # Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
      # Enable expirations.
      ExpiresActive On

      # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
      ExpiresDefault A1209600

      <FilesMatch \.php$>
        # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
        # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
        # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
        # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
        # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
        ExpiresActive Off
      </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>

    # Various rewrite rules.
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/techiequickie/"
      RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]

      # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period. This
      # includes directories used by version control systems such as Subversion or
      # Git to store control files. Files whose names begin with a period, as well
      # as the control files used by CVS, are protected by the FilesMatch directive
      # above.
      #
      # NOTE: This only works when mod_rewrite is loaded. Without mod_rewrite, it is
      # not possible to block access to entire directories from .htaccess, because
      # <DirectoryMatch> is not allowed here.
      #
      # If you do not have mod_rewrite installed, you should remove these
      # directories from your webroot or otherwise protect them from being
      # downloaded.
      RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

      # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
      # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
      # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
      #
      # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
      # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
      # uncomment the following:
      # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
      # RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
      #
      # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
      # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
      # uncomment the following:
      # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
      # RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

      # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
      # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
      # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
      # modify the following line:
      # RewriteBase /drupal
      #
      # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
      # uncomment the following line:
      # RewriteBase /

      # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
      # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
      RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

      # Various rewrite rules.


      # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
      # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
      <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
        RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

        # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
        RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

        # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
        RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
        RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

        <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
          # Serve correct encoding type.
          Header set Content-Encoding gzip
          # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
          Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
        </FilesMatch>
      </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: pls see my edited question, and feel free to edit, as I am confused where to add the lines that you gave me I tried to do as u said but is giving me an internal error

Comment: sry but that is just not working!

Comment: Are you getting some err ? like a 500 or something ?

Comment: no I am not getting it like that its just not working!

Comment: You mean no error messages in screen ?

Answer (score 0):

If the folder name isn't critical, folder under files e.g. mydomain.com/sites/default/files/test is also possible. No further adjustments needed.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add the following linein the Drupal7 .htaccess file (around line 112):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^YOUR_FOLDER_HERE
```

The result should be similar to:

```
# Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
# index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^YOUR_FOLDER_HERE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

2) then create a .htaccess on your custom folder. Add/adjust the following rules

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /producton/
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
</IfModule>
```

With these settings you can install WordPress, CMSMS and probably many others webappp inside a "Drupal environment".