# How can I have drupal ignore a specific folder with another site within?

Tags: redirection, uri

I am having a multilingual website at www.example.gr which runs Drupal 7. Inside Drupal installation I have placed a folder with an opencart installation. I am able to access www.example.gr/eshop/index.php yet I cannot access www.example.gr/eshop/admin because drupal redirects me to www.example.gr/el/eshop/admin which obviously doesn't exist. Any ideas about how to fix that?

Comment: I suspect you might find your answer here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51197/make-a-folder-inside-the-drupal-installation-public

Comment: The opencart folder is located on the Drupal root directory or under sites/ folder? Could you add how is the current vhost you're using?

Comment: @othermachines I tried the solution there but it didn't work! It is located in the Drupal root directory. The folder is named eshop. What do you mean by current vhost?